# Pandas Dataframes operation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I use pandas dataframes to process my dataset. I have 3 columns, airport_id airline_id and delay. I want to remove all origin airports that have less than 5 airlines.

I did this:

```
grouped_size = df.groupby(['OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID','ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID']).size()
```

Which gives me the number of airlines per airport(I hope) but I do not know how to remove the ones with less than 5 airlines. Thank you!

Comment: `df = df[df.groupby(['OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID','ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID']).transform('count') >= 5]`?

Comment: @coldspeed or use `groupby(...).filter(...)` - save materialising a Series if it's not being used for anything?

Comment: @JonClements, I'm guessing `filter` would require `lambda`? If so, I'm all in favour of avoiding `lamda` :).

Comment: @coldspeed I get this error "ValueError: Boolean array expected for the condition, not float64"

Comment: @KaanYolsever Please copy the entire command properly.

Comment: @coldspeed I did but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
grouped_size = df.groupby(['OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID','ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID']).size().reset_index()
grouped_size.columns = ['OP_CARRIER_AIRLINE_ID','ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID', 'size']
hi_mask = grouped_size['size'] > 5
grouped_size = grouped_size[hi_mask]
```

Comment: @ thank you but i get this error: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: one thing is when I do this I lose my other columns. How can I do this while preserving them in the output data structure?

Comment: Once you do a `groupby`, you are basically asking pandas to count on the base dataframe. Hence, you no more are working with the base dataframe. If you want to pick only the those that satisfy this criteria, you will need to `merge` the groupy df with the base df, and filter again.